# How to find out if your Linux server has a FC card or not?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to know if a LINUX server has a FC card  ? If yes what should I search for proably in dmesg ?

Answer (score 2):

I usually start with `lspci`.   If you know what type of card you can grep for that:

```
lspci | grep -i emulex

    13:00.0 Fibre Channel: Emulex Corporation Zephyr-X LightPulse Fibre Channel Host Adapter (rev 02)
    13:00.1 Fibre Channel: Emulex Corporation Zephyr-X LightPulse Fibre Channel Host Adapter (rev 02)
```

From the output you should be able to work out who made the card then refer to the vendor's support for the correct drivers/firmware.

Comment: Why not directly grep for it:
lspci | grep -i fibre

Comment: Thanks - very helpful  . I got a lot of appreciation from my team for this . Is there a method to capture WWN numbers of FC HBA’s ?

Comment: See this kbase article for RedHat derived systems (to get WWN data):

http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-9937

The ``sg_utils`` are very helpful.